# Extract last value of the selected option multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

How can I extract the value of the last option selected in a multiselect dropdrown?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the `:selected` and `:last` selectors:

```
var foo = $('select option:selected:last').val();
```

Comment: This gets to the last value of the array, what I want is you choose to click.
//
Con esto coge el último valor del array, lo que yo quiero es el que seleccione al hacer click.

Comment: @LuisCañasMosh but your question is different.